# It is necessary to check if the user wrote 2 or more words

Tags: php

It is necessary to check if the user wrote 2 or more words, if less, then an error should be generated. This must be done using the "explode" method.

**my code**

```
<input type="text" name="films" class="form-control mb-3">

<?php   
$films = $_POST['films'];

if(explode(',', $films) < 2) {
    echo 'error';
} else {
    echo $films;
}
```

Comment: [Almost there](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Comment: Another way could be using [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) like `substr_count($films, ',') == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) method to count the explode result:

```
if (count(explode(',', $films)) < 2)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

@ztom answer's is correct but you can make it even better to handle user separator or mistyping (empty bloc, multiple comma, etc):

```
if (count(array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $films))) < 2)
...
```